# Botbuilder replay commands

Tags: botframework

Our scenario is something like this

- User issues a command to our bot
- Bot will ask user to sign-in if user is not singed in
- After user signs-in then bot should remember and run the command

Technically this can be achieved if our core code to process the command is not dependent on TurnContext or Activity within it, but we use that heavily and to a deeper extent. Also with this approach it will mean that we will have to write all of our code such that it is not dependent on botBuilder classes.

Before going down this route I wanted to check if there is any generic way to achieve this, something like store the whole request (which does not seem possible) and then just replay it once sign-in is complete.

Our development environment is node.

Comment: is your issue resolved?